How to delete an element from a folder name
Let's say I have a folder that contains a lot of subfolders. These subfolders all have [Extra] at the end of their name.
Is there a simple way to delete all those [Extra] in one go?
I tried to adapt a code I found about renaming files, but it didn't work. Something like this:
import os
from pathlib import Path

path = r"C:\Test"
suffix = "[Extra]"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:
        if name.endswith(suffix):
            directoryPath = os.path.join(root, name)
            parentDirectory = Path(directoryPath).parent
            os.chdir(parentDirectory)
            os.remove(suffix)


Are you asking how to delete the subfolders, or are you asking how to rename them so that they no longer end in [Extra] ?

"but it didn't work": Details, please.

@GillesQuénot , the variable path has a 'C:' , its our best OS windows :)

Build the new pathname and use os.rename.  As of Python 3.9, there is a handy str.removesuffix()] method:
import os

path = r'C:\Test'
suffix = '[Extra]'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:
        if name.endswith(suffix):
            old = os.path.join(root, name)
            new = old.removesuffix(suffix)
            os.rename(old, new)

Before:
C:\>tree TEST
C:\TEST
├───a[Extra]
└───b[Extra]
    ├───c[Extra]
    └───d[Extra]

After:
C:\>tree TEST
C:\TEST
├───a
└───b
    ├───c
    └───d


os.remove(suffix) is intended for deleting files, not directories.
Try this instead:
path = r"C:\Test"
suffix = "[Extra]"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:
        if name.endswith(suffix):
            old_dir_path = os.path.join(root, name)
            new_name = name[: -len(suffix)].strip()
            new_dir_path = os.path.join(root, new_name)
            os.rename(old_dir_path, new_dir_path)

print("Renaming completed!") 


Your script has a conceptual issue: you are treating the folder as if it were a file while attempting to remove the suffix. Here's the correct approach to rename a folder and remove the [Extra] suffix:
import os

path = r"C:\Test"
suffix = "[Extra]"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:

        if name.endswith(suffix):
            old_folder_path = os.path.join(root, name)
            new_name = name[: -len(suffix)].strip()
            new_folder_path = os.path.join(root, new_name)
            os.rename(old_folder_path, new_folder_path)


Using rename command in WSL shell:
cd directory
rename 's/\[Extra\]//' */    


There are various ways of doing this, but one option is:
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(r"C:\Test")
suffix = "[Extra]"

# use glob to list get everything in path
for p in path.glob("*"):
    if p.is_dir() and p.name.endswith(suffix):
        # rename directories that end with your suffix
        p.rename(str(p)[:-len(suffix)])

